# Fetching duplicate records based on a column value in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle10g

So I have a customer database which has Customer_Account_ID, Phone_No and Alt_Phone_No. Now the Alt_Phone_No can have a number value or it can have blank. I want a output where the data is in below format:

Let’s say customer id is 12345678
Phone numbers are 4021234444 and 4022221234
We should have two rows on the spreadsheet:

```
Customer ID       Phone number  
12345678            4021234444
12345678            4022221234
```

If there is no value in Alt_Phone_No, then there shouldn't be any second entry i.e. need just the Customer ID and Phone Number in such case.

What I have roughly came up is with below:

```
SELECT Customer_Account_ID, Phone_No FROM Table_A a, 
  (SELECT Customer_Account_ID,  Phone_No FROM Table_A, Table_B
where Table_A.Cust_ID = Table_B.Cust_ID 
and condition = ' ' /*filter needed as per requirements*/
UNION ALL
SELECT Customer_Account_ID,  Alt_Phone_No FROM Table_A, Table_B
where Table_A.Cust_ID = Table_B.Cust_ID 
and condition = ' ' /*filter needed as per requirements*/ ) b
where a.Cust_ID = b.Cust_ID
and rownum < 1000 /*need rownum for testing sample data as the original data is too large*/
order by a.Cust_Id
```

I believe the query is incorrect. Would appreciate all the suggestions and inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all`:

```
select customerid, phonenumber
from t
union all
select customerid, altphonenumber
from t
where altphonenumber is not null;
```

Comment: I tried Union All and I don't think this is working. Even if the Customer has 2 phone numbers, the result set has only set of them, i.e. the result is not in the format specified. Just one row is being returned while there should be two, one for each phone numbers.

Comment: @Aabhish . . . This returns both the numbers.  However, if you want rows for a customer to be together, you would need to add `order by customerid`.

Comment: . . Please see the query mentioned in the question.